# Mandrill "Unknown_Template" Issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mandrill

I am using mandrill API to send emails & the response I am getting is:

"Unknown_template".

Now, I know that a template with that name is not created in my mandrill account. But, the question I have is if I create a new template with that name, would mandrill send the emails which were meant to be sent previously & if yes, is there a way to avoid it?

Thanks

Comment: Every template name is uniq,To avoid sending the template you have update the mailer.

Comment: I am asking if I create the template now, would mandrill retry sending those mails which were previousuly failed